# Failed to rotate AWS secret even though lambda test event passes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I created a lambda for a secret rotation, quite simple:

```
import os
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    new_secret = os.urandom(32).hex()

    secret_arn = event['SecretId']

    client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
    response = client.update_secret(SecretId=secret_arn, SecretString=new_secret)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps({'Message': 'Secret rotation successful'})
    }
```

I have a test event with a proper ARN which works - the secret updates as it's supposed to. However, when I go over to the secrets manager, and edit the "Rotation Configuration" with my new lambda, all I get is `Failed to rotate the secret`. Nothing more, nothing else. Console shows nothing, CloudWatch shows nothing. I tried both versions of the lambda `secret_arn` has proper ARN of the secret I'm rotating, and one where it's just `SecretId`.

This is my execution role for the lambda:

1st policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "arn:aws:logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "Resource": "placeholder"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:placeholder:log-group:/aws/lambda/SecretRotation:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2nd policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUpdateSecret",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:placeholder:secret:*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Trust relationship:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "secretsmanager.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Given all this, and the fact the test event works, I'm out of ideas. I just don't understand what I'm missing. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Perhaps cloudtrail contains a more meaningful message?

Comment: @Paolo yup, it gives me this: 
"errorMessage": "Secrets Manager cannot invoke the specified Lambda function. Ensure that the function policy grants access to the principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com."

But still, I added secretsmanager to trust?

Comment: fixed, edited the post

Comment: Follow this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-required-permissions-function.html

Answer (score 0):

So, Cloudtrail told me this:

```
"errorMessage": "Secrets Manager cannot invoke the specified Lambda function. Ensure that the function policy grants access to the principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com."
```

It was solved by doing this:

```
aws lambda add-permission \
  --function-name your-lambda-arn \
  --principal secretsmanager.amazonaws.com \
  --action lambda:InvokeFunction \
  --statement-id SecretsManagerAccess
```

Not very clear why, because I already had my permissions set properly.